# The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, import-from-excel

I am developing a asp.net web application which will export excel sheet data to sql server table

I have just installed Access Database Engine and i have also changed the name of excel many times

private void InsertExcelRecords(string FilePath)
    {
        ExcelConn(FilePath);

```
    Query = string.Format("Select [Post ID],[ConsumerNo],[BillingPeriod],[BranchCode],[Amount],[Paymentdate],[Createdby],[Createddate],[BankName] FROM[{0}]", "Sheet");
    OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(Query, Econ);
    Econ.Open();

        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Econ);
        Econ.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);
        DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];
   connection();
   //creating object of SqlBulkCopy  
   SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
   //assigning Destination table name  
   objbulk.DestinationTableName = "testingnationalbank";
    //Mapping Table column  
    objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ConsumerNo", "consumerno");
   objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("BillingPeriod", "billingperiod");
   objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("BranchCode", "branchcode");
   //objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Designation", "Designation");
   //inserting Datatable Records to DataBase  
   con.Open();
   objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
   con.Close();


}
```

When i run this code it show error which is written below:

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Sheet' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.  Source Error:

Comment: Dont know why, but it usually have to access the sheet using `from [sheetName$]`

Comment: I have tried this from [sheetName$] but it does not worked